# DigestAuth in Sails v0.11

Tags: sails.js

Trying to integrate digest `auth` in sails. Using `passport-http` module for it . https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http

This is the policy I have defined.

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

var passport = require('passport');
var Strategy = require('passport-http').DigestStrategy;

passport.use(new Strategy({ qop: 'auth' },
  function(username, cb) {
    console.log("in strategy");

    user = { id: 1, username: 'postman', password: 'password', displayName: 'Postman', emails: [ { value: 'postman@example.com' } ] }
    if(username == user.username) {
        return cb(null,user,user.password)
    }
    else{
        return cb(null,false)
    }
  }
));

passport.authenticate('digest',{session: false});

next();

};
```

Now in express the passport.authenticate function returns in case of error but in case of sails , it does not return here as a middle-ware. Please point me in the right direction , spent a lot of time on this .

I want to basically return a not authorized in case of wrong headers else move on to the controller action.